# Feedback and system linearity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

The following notes have a nice discussion of how feedback can make the response of a nonlinear static system more linear, i.e. reduce nonlinear distortion (at the expense of gain).
[https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/ee102/fdbk-static.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/ee102/fdbk-static.pdf)

Is there similar reasoning for a nonlinear dynamic system?

For example, are there conditions under which the mapping from $u(\cdot)$ to $y(\cdot)$ in the closed loop system $\dot{y}=f(y,u-ky)$ is more linear than in the open loop system $\dot{y}=f(y,u)$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there exists a method doing such a linearization also for dynamic nonlinear systems and it is called feedback linearization. However, they do not use a linear feedback as you stated in the question, but rather a nonlinear state feedback of the form $$ u(x) = \alpha(x) + \beta(x)\nu, $$ along with a change of variables $z = T(x)$ which render the system linear from $\nu(\cdot)$ to $y(\cdot)$. There exists the full state feedback linearization and the input-output linearization, where the system is only partly linearized to achieve only a linear input-output behaviour. The conditions for the existance of such a feedback law and the feedback law along with the change of variables $T(\cdot)$ involve the relative degree of the system and are detailed in Chapter 13 of Khalil: Nonlinear Systems. Prentice Hall, 2002.

Comment: Is it accurate to say that feedback linearization uses part of the control input to "cancel" nonlinear  terms in the system model?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The feedback linearization applies only for nonlinear but input affine systems, i.e. $\dot{x} = f(x)+g(x)u$. Then, the input as stated in the answer is a linear combination of $\alpha(x)$ (roughly speaking, for cancelling $f(x)$) and $\beta(x)\nu$ (roughly speaking, for cancelling $g(x)$). This is exactly shown in Example 1 in Chapter 13.1 of the book of Khalil

Comment: I understand the feedback linearization concept. I think the sense in which feedback makes a static system more linear in the notes above (pages 16-23) is different. The following dynamic example may be similar to the notes. In the second order scalar system $m\ddot{x}+c(\dot{x})+k(x)=u$ let $c(\cdot)$ and $k(\cdot)$ be nonlinear functions in the sectors $[0,c_1]$ and $[0,k_1]$. A PD controller $u=\bar{u}-Kx-C\dot{x}$ with $C\gg c_1$ and $K\gg k_1$ would make the mapping $\bar{u}$ to $x$ more linear and less sensitive to variability. Is this correct? If so, is there a more general formulation?

Comment: Hi, @Siva The notion of "more linear" needs a more firm ground. For a general nonlinear system, high gain linear controllers do not have that property even when they are stabilizing. The origin of $\dot x = \sin(u)$ is stabilized by $u=-kx$ but the stability region shrinks as $k \to \infty.$ For feedback linearizable systems, the closest I'm aware of is "High-gain feedback in non-linear control systems" (Marino, 1985). Even then, you'd need your system to be minimum phase so you can ramp up the gain.

Comment: Hi @RollenS.D'Souza, I realize (1) I have to find something more precise for "more linear", (2) I should specify more structure for the system, at least control affine or maybe even feedback linearizable. Could you please post as an answer so I can accept it? Also, your example $\dot{x}=\sin(u)$ is great. It would be insightful to learn your reasoning for how you came up with it.

Comment: Thank you also to @Trb2. Collectively, both your answers helped clarify things for me.